# hitting f5 after clicking the submit button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a **PHP** application where users can apply for a bonus. But there is a confirmation page before the bonus redemption code runs. 
The issue is that in **IE**, if you hit `f5` right after you click the continue button, the confirmation page refreshes while the bonus redemption code had already been triggered by the continue button and actually goes through. But because the user still sees the confirmation page, they would hit the continue button again and now they get an error cause they are already registered.

Is there a way i can disable the `f5` button using `javascript`? Is this the best way to go about this? I have tried many scripts i found online to do this, but none of them achieves it. Is there a better way I can go about this? Perhaps from the application side?

Comment: Server side check (in database) would be better.

Comment: Can we see the relevant code?

Comment: And what about ctrl-r shirt-r right click, button in browser? You can not stop it. Sounds like you need a better set up with the redemption.  Figure out what causes it.

Comment: i'm agree with Sheikh, server side check maybe a good way, if you using javascript to do that, it's still have a chance not work and for security reason, people can disable javascript in their browser.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: If the outcome of claiming a bonus is databased, you can load existing claims on your confirmation screen and test that one already exists.

---

Edit: the other neat trick you can do is serailize/json_encode the $_POST and produce a hash from this, store it in the database or user session, and test against it.

---

I would generate and database a single use token (hash) for the form as a hidden field, if post data is re-sumbited, the token would have already been consumed, and you can invalidate the post request.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of methods to solve your issue:

Checkout here: http://bjw.co.nz/developer/general/75-how-to-prevent-form-resubmission

I have been using second method (Using sessions) and it's really working well.